# Moving armature-bone moves the whole character

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I just set up a character rig and am trying to animate it now. However, when I move this one armature it simply moves the whole character but the mesh itself doesn't move. When I try to rotate this bone it also rotates the whole character.

Here's a photo of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5H6r.jpg

What it's supposed to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CwVz.jpg

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 1):

The bone is doing what it's meant to be doing; there's nothing wrong with that. The difference is that in the second image the legs have an IK rig (shown by the yellow bones on the shins of the legs), meaning that when the body moves it will bend the legs accordingly. You'll need to set that up and then you should be all good.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! I feel really silly for asking this question.